# How to export Excel CSV with utf-8 and read into Java?

Tags: java, excel, csv

I have excel spreadsheet which contain many "Chinese(zh-TW)" & "English(en-US)" word together and this data need to import to a database table with utf-8 encoding.
My first try was use Excel "Save-As" function to export data as CSV. However, the data was not able to read correctly since Excel is not allow to change the character encoding for "Save-AS" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching, I found the easy way to complete the task is following below steps:

Save the Excel sheet as "Unicode Text (.txt)" (Excel encode in UTF16 and use TAB to delimited each column.
[image]

Below is Java code snippet to read the content of this Excel unicode exported file:

```
File dataFile = new File("my-unicode-file-exported.txt"));
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(dataFile), "UTF-16");     
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);        

String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // splits by TAB
    String elements = line.split("\t");

    // process each element
    String element_01 = elements[0];
    String element_02 = elements[1];
    .....   
}

br.close();
```